# Populate checkbox list depending on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

I am creating a form that will populate a div with checkboxes related to media files that a usergroup has uploaded. Basically, if the user selects the name of the group from a dropdown menu, all associated media files will appear in a div in checkbox form.

The dropdown menu receives it's options from the database, the options will not always be a known quantity.

```
<select name="gpname" id="gpname">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usergroups ORDER BY groupname");            
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
     echo ('<option value="'); echo ($row['groupname']); echo('">'); echo $row['groupname']; echo('</option>');
}; ?>
</select>
```

Then, here is the div:

```
<div style="overflow: auto; width: 500px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #c4c4c4; padding-left: 5px" id="medialist"></div>
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a PHP file that receives the selected option and display the checkbox form.

With Ajax, call the PHP file with the selected option and set the content into the div.

```
function setCheckforms(){

var selectedOption = document.getElementById("gpname").value;

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: 'file.php',
        data: {option:selectedOption},
        success: function(data){
            $('#medialist').html(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
        }
    });

}
```

Remember to call the function whenever the option change.

```
<select name="gpname" id="gpname" onchange="setCheckforms()">
```

My code is not tested. If you have problems, let me know :D

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this is exactly what I needed. I accepted your solution, but I can't upvote yet because of my rep.

Comment: @Collucin you can use this:
`<select name="gpname" id="gpname" onchange="setCheckforms(this.value)">`
and
`function setCheckforms(selectedOption){ bla bla bla }`
and remember delete this line:
`var selectedOption = document.getElementById("gpname").value;`

with this, you save one line of code! :P